# Передать ID элемента в другой компонент

Tags: битрикс, компоненты

Есть два компонента: «Новости» и «Каталог». Нужно, чтобы в зависимости от текущего товара в каталоге выводилась соответствующая новость.

По идее, функционировать должно так: если вручную вводим ID, а нужно чтобы он динамически вытаскивал.

```
<?$GLOBALS['arrFilter'] = array("PROPERTY_53" => "ELEMENT_ID 4-го инфоблока на этой странице");?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "action", 
    array(
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "action",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "action",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "5",

);?><br>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog", 
    "catalog_new", 
    array(
        "DETAIL_SHOW_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "SECTION_SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "4",

);?><br>
```

**Обновление**

Сделал с `GetList`, но в результате выводит много ID, а нужный не выводит. Подскажите, что не так. Вот код:

```
<?if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
{
$iblock = 4; //id инфоблока 
$code = $arResult["CODE"]; //код товара 
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL"); 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$iblock, "CODE"=>$code); 

$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
 while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) 
 { $arFields = $ob->GetFields(); 
        ?><pre><?print_r($arFields["ID"]);?></pre><?
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас не используется ЧПУ - то просто вытаскиваете ID из `$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]`, например. Если есть ЧПУ по символьному коду элемента - при помощи `CIBlockElement::GetList` выбираете элемент по коду и получаете его ID.

**Обновление**

Получить `id` по коду можно так:

```
$iblock = 1; //id инфоблока
$code = 'tovar'; //код товара

$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$iblock, "CODE"=>$code);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    echo $arFields["ID"];
}
```

Если `ID` непосредственно есть в адресной строке - получаете адресную строку через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и например при помощи `substr()` вытаскиваете `ID`.

Comment: ЧПУ используется, можно подробнее как GetList использовать? Я с его помощью тоже пробывал, только не получилось у меня.

Comment: $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>4));
  while($ob = $res->GetNext()){
 }

Comment: А если ЧПУ настроено не по символьному коду, а а вот так #SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_ID#/

Comment: $code = 'tovar'; //код товара - это значение где брать?

Comment: если в компоненте каталога(карточка товара) - то $arResult["CODE"]

Comment: Вернее вывелись ID всех элементов из других разделов.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи лучше всего использовать свойство инфоблока "Привязка к элементу".
В инфоблоке "Каталог" создайте свойства типа "Привязка к элементу" и привязывайте к нему нужную новость.

Comment: Ваш метод не получается. У меня сслыка вида /catalog/tovary-dlya-ofisa-kantstovary/demonstratsionnoe-oborudovanie/doski-dlya-pisma-i-informatsii-25/305501/?clear_cache=Y где 305501 - ID, который мне нужен, но если делаю фильтр <?$GLOBALS['arrFilter'] = array("PROPERTY_53" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]);?> ничего не меняется.